# Angular UI Modal: Inserting an Image into the modal body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I am very new to AngularJS and have to integrate the Angular UI bootstrap to an existing AngularJS application.

Inside the modal I have to place a screenshot and that's it. No unnecessary clutter. But I am unable to figure it out. There is a lot of messy stuff in the code and I am not able to do that.

I don't want the selected items and the also the logs in the console too. Just a simple modal which shows screenshot(image) in it and that's it. Can anyone guide me?

Here is the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      .btn-custom{
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 20px;
        bottom: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl as $ctrl" class="modal-demo">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Here's what we are cooking new for you!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
          <!-- <img ng-src={{source}} class="img-responsive"> -->
          <img ng-src="{{source}}" id="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $ctrl.selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ $ctrl.selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">OK</button> -->
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
    <!-- <script type="text/ng-template" id="stackedModal.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-{{name}}">The {{name}} modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-{{name}}">
            Having multiple modals open at once is probably bad UX but it's technically possible.
        </div>
    </script> -->

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-custom" ng-click="$ctrl.open()">Open me!</button>
    <!-- <div ng-show="$ctrl.selected">Selection from a modal: {{ $ctrl.selected }}</div> -->
    <div class="modal-parent">
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Script.js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($uibModal, $log, $document) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  // $ctrl.source = Screenshot.png;

  $ctrl.animationsEnabled = true;

  $ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ?
      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem,
      resolve: {
         items: function () {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $ctrl.openComponentModal = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      component: 'modalComponent',
      resolve: {
        source: function(){
          return $ctrl.source;
        }
        // ,
        // items: function () {
        //   return $ctrl.items;
        // }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('modal-component dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $ctrl.openMultipleModals = function () {
    $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title-bottom',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body-bottom',
      templateUrl: 'stackedModal.html',
      size: 'sm',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'bottom';
      }
    });

    $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title-top',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body-top',
      templateUrl: 'stackedModal.html',
      size: 'sm',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'top';
      }
    });
  };

  $ctrl.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $ctrl.animationsEnabled = !$ctrl.animationsEnabled;
  };
});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, items) { //In case of any changes, change the source to items
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = items;
  $ctrl.selected = {
    item: $ctrl.items[0]
  };

  $ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected.item);
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});

// Please note that the close and dismiss bindings are from $uibModalInstance.

//Change ui.bootstrap.demo to powerMe App

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').component('modalComponent', {
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  bindings: {
    resolve: '<',
    close: '&',
    dismiss: '&'
  },
  controller: function () {
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.$onInit = function () {
      $ctrl.items = $ctrl.resolve.items;
      $ctrl.selected = {
        item: $ctrl.items[0]
      };
    };

    $ctrl.ok = function () {
      $ctrl.close({$value: $ctrl.selected.item});
    };

    $ctrl.cancel = function () {
      $ctrl.dismiss({$value: 'cancel'});
    };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your modified code with image in the modal body

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($uibModal, $log, $document) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  

  $ctrl.animationsEnabled = true;

  $ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ?
      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem,
      resolve: {
         items: function () {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });
  };


  $ctrl.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $ctrl.animationsEnabled = !$ctrl.animationsEnabled;
  };
});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, items) { //In case of any changes, change the source to items
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.source = "https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mac.jpg";


  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      .btn-custom{
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 20px;
        bottom: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl as $ctrl" class="modal-demo">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Here's what we are cooking new for you!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
          <img ng-src={{$ctrl.source}} class="img-responsive">
         
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">OK</button> -->
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-custom" ng-click="$ctrl.open()">Open me!</button>
    <div class="modal-parent">
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there anyway where we can remove all the unnecessary code which doesn't participate in the final view because when I am removing it, everything is getting messed up.

Comment: i have removed the unwanted code in the above code snippet